# Actual path in maximum path sum in binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, graph-traversal

I'm trying to store and print the actual path in the problem of finding maximum path sum in a binary tree. I already know how to find the maximum path sum (below), but how can we add a snippet to output the actual path?

```
private int maxSum;
public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
findMax(root);
return maxSum;
}

private int findMax(TreeNode p) {
if (p == null) return 0;
int left = findMax(p.left);
int right = findMax(p.right);
maxSum = Math.max(p.val + left + right, maxSum);
int ret = p.val + Math.max(left, right);
return ret > 0 ? ret : 0;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 `max` operations. These are the key. Whenever you decide a max, you have important information about the max sum path. Figure out how to record it. Hint: You'll need to record the root of the subtree that contains the max, plus, for each node in that subtree (but you'll have to record it for all nodes because you don't know the subtree in advance). You also need to record which child of `p` lies on the max weight path from `p` to a leaf.

Comment: @Gene thanks for the hints. I appreciate the code snippet though.

Comment: This looks like homework or a learning problem. You won't learn much from a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

May you can try this.

```
static class Node {
        
        int pathSum;
        List<Integer> path;
        
        Node(int pathSum) {
            this.pathSum = pathSum;
            this.path = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    
    
    public List<Integer> maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        
        solve(root);
        return maxPathTrace;
        
    }
    
    
    int maxPath = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    List<Integer> maxPathTrace = new ArrayList<>();

    public Node solve(TreeNode root) {

        if ( root == null) return new Node(0);
                
        Node leftNode = solve(root.left);
        Node rightNode = solve(root.right);
        
        int leftGain = Math.max(leftNode.pathSum, 0);
        int rightGain = Math.max(rightNode.pathSum, 0);
        
        int resultGain = leftGain + rightGain + root.val;
       
        // calculate max path and note it down    
        if ( resultGain > maxPath) {
            maxPathTrace.clear();
                if ( leftNode.pathSum >= 0) {
                    maxPathTrace.addAll(leftNode.path);
                }
                maxPathTrace.add(root.val);
                if ( rightNode.pathSum >= 0) {
                    maxPathTrace.addAll(rightNode.path);
                }
        }
         maxPath = Math.max(resultGain, maxPath);
        
        
        //calculate return path
        Node resultNode = new Node(Math.max(leftGain + root.val , rightGain + root.val));
        if ( leftGain > rightGain ) {
            if ( leftNode.pathSum >= 0) {
                resultNode.path.addAll(leftNode.path);
            }
            resultNode.path.add(root.val);
        } else {
             resultNode.path.add(root.val);
            if ( rightNode.pathSum >= 0) {
               resultNode.path.addAll(rightNode.path);
            }   
        }
        
        
        return resultNode;
        
    }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.